# Check if a table exists in Hive in pyspark sparksession

Tags: python, pyspark, hive

I have the  following code. What I am trying to achieve is to check if a table already exists in a database in Hive. If yes, then append new data into. If not then create a new table.

```
 if "table1" in sqlContext.tableNames("db1"):
    df.write.format("orc").mode("append").insertInto("db1.table1")
 else:
    df.write.format("orc").saveAsTable("db1.table1")
```

But I am getting this error:

```
NameError: name 'sqlContext' is not defined
```

I am using spark session in Pyspark with Jupyter Notebook:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your Apache Spark version. If your Spark version is 1.x then you need to do as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

Comment: My spark version is 2.3.0.2

Comment: I am getting NameError: name 'sc' is not defined using the code

Comment: from pyspark import SparkContext
sc =SparkContext.getOrCreate()